# Whats the error in following code (php)

Tags: php, foreach

```
<?php
foreach($menu_names as $menu_name){
$i=0;
echo "<li><a href='?subj=" .$subjects_ids[$i]. " '>".$menu_name."</a></li>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

`$subjects_ids` is an array which contains three values of `1`, `2` and `3`. But the link created here in HTML only contains `?subj=3` for all three `$menu_name`. The first `$menu_name` should have `subj=1` and second should have `2` and third should have `3`.

Comment: I have checked the $subjects_ids array in other loop it echoing all three values 1,2 and 3 respectively. But don't know whats happening here.

Comment: did you try out the below solutions.

Comment: @yusufiqbalpk it is because for every loop you are setting the value of $i to 0; to change the value for $i; you need to declare it outside of foreach loop. check my answer.

Comment: Oops that was a blunder. Thanks very much and muaahh everyone for your great help. Love the Stack Overflow community for their great guidelines. Love for all

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL how did you make inline block codes ?

Comment: Now! click on Tick mark.. let them give credits to users..

Comment: @Rafee There is no tick mark because you just commented didn't give an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i=0;
foreach($menu_names as $menu_name){
    echo "<li><a href='?subj=" .$subjects_ids[$i]. " '>".$menu_name."</a></li>";
    $i++;
}
```

place `$i=0;` outside of the loop.

Explanation:

when you place `$i` variable inside the foreach loop and set it's value to `0`. every time the data is looped value of `$i` will be set to $i=0; hence you should place it on outside the foreach loop.

Comment: You are answering my question second time. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are setting $i = 0 everytime in the loop.

```
$i=0;
foreach($menu_names as $menu_name){
  echo "<li><a href='?subj=" .$subjects_ids[$i]. " '>".$menu_name."</a></li>";
  $i++;
}
```

is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($menu_names as $menu_name){
echo "<li><a href='?subj=" .$subjects_ids[$i]. " '>".$menu_name."</a></li>";
$i++;
}
?>
```

you have initialized your $i variable inside the loop it should be initialized before the loop starts , therefore its value remains same and add the id 3 in all a tags

Answer (score 0):

You initialize $i var on each iteration so it points to element with index 0 always.
Just remove

```
$i=0;
```